# Undefined Variable taskid in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am working on view and i want to print task id from database in my view
 following is my Controller function

Controller :-

```
 function editMilestone($editid){
        //, $taskid) {

        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $id = $session_data['id'];
            $username = $session_data['username'];
            $is_master_admin = $session_data['master'];
            $imagethumb = $session_data['imagethumb'];
            $status_result = $this->getstatus->getEnumValues(MILESTONE, 'status');
            $result = $this->milestonemodel->getEditMilestone($editid , $taskid);

            $pendingbug = $this->bugmodel->getBug($id, $is_master_admin);
            $pendingtask = $this->taskmodel->getTask($id, $is_master_admin);
            if ($result == true) {
                $session_msg_data = $this->session->userdata('msg');
                if (isset($session_msg_data) && !empty($session_msg_data)) {
                    $milestonemsg = isset($session_msg_data['milestonemsg']) ? $session_msg_data['milestonemsg'] : '';
                    $milestoneopt = isset($session_msg_data['milestoneopt']) ? $session_msg_data['milestoneopt'] : '';
                    $this->session->unset_userdata('msg');
                } else {
                    $milestonemsg = '';
                    $milestoneopt = '';
                }
                $data = '';
                $data = array('username' => $username,
                    'is_master_admin' => $is_master_admin,
                    'imagethumb' => $imagethumb,
                    'result' => $result,
                    'taskid' => $taskid,
                    //'editid'=>$editid,
                    'status_result' => $status_result,
                    'profileopt' => $milestoneopt,
                    'profilemsg' => $milestonemsg,
                    'pendingtask' => $pendingtask,
                    'pendingbug' => $pendingbug
                );
                $this->load->view('milestone/edit_milestone', $data);
            } else {
                redirect('task', 'refresh');
            }
        } else {
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('home/logout', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Model :-

```
function getEditMilestone($id){
        //, $taskid) {
        $status = array(PUBLISH, UNPUBLISH, BLOCK);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from(MILESTONE);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        //$this->db->where('taskid', $taskid);
        $this->db->where_in('status', $status);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        //echo $this->db-last_query();

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

VIEW :- Milestone View

```
<div class="message">
                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class="body">
                    <?php
                    echo '<b> <U> Task Title </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
                    echo $milestone_row->tasktitle;
                    echo '<br/>';
                    echo '<b> <U> Workspace Title </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
                    echo $milestone_row->workspacetitle;
                    echo '<br/>';
                    echo '<b> <U> Description </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
                    echo $milestone_row->description;
                    echo '<br/>';
                    echo '<b> <U> Hours </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
                    echo $milestone_row->esthours;
                    echo 'hrs';
                    echo '<br/>';
                    echo '<b> <U> Minutes </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
                    echo $milestone_row->estmin;
                    echo'mins';
                    echo '<br/>';
                    ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>milestone/editMilestone/<?php echo $milestone_row->id;?>">Edit</a>
            </div>
```

When i click on edit link from above view it will transfer to editMilestone from controller and it wil transfer to to another view that is edit_milestone

View :- edit_milestone

```
<?php
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form_add_milestone');
echo form_open('milestone/validateEditMilestone/'.$result[0]->id.'/'.$taskid, $attributes);
?>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $taskid; ?>" name="taskid" />
```

I would like to print my taskid here from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code. you are using `$taskid` when its not initialized in following line,

`$result = $this->milestonemodel->getEditMilestone($editid , $taskid);`
and when you put that value in `$data` it does not work because there is no value in `$taskid`
you should pass `$taskid` as parameter in  Milestone View or create another query to fetch it from db.

Comment: yes exactly problem is there.
so where should i defined $ taskid?

Comment: pass it as a second paramter to `editMilestone`. in Milestone View , edit anchor write `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>milestone/editMilestone/<?php echo $milestone_row->id;?>/<?php echo $milestone_row->taskid;?>">Edit</a>`

Comment: i will tell you if any further error or bug will occur..
hope u will give me reply further in future